# Amazon's scrolling Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i would like to implement an effect that i saw at amazon and zalando. On top of the product info page is an image on the left side and a long description on the right side. If i scroll down, the image stays at the top of my screen, untill the right side reaches its end, than it stops scroling.

Examples:
https://www.zalando.de/levis-standard-crew-sweatshirt-caviar-le221j03m-q11.html

https://www.amazon.de/Bluetooth-Kopfh%C3%B6rer-Wasserdicht-Sportkopfh%C3%B6rer-Klangprofil-New-Model/dp/B08C7C29JK/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2CF2HKPS0ISI2&dchild=1&keywords=bluetooth%2Bkopfh%C3%B6rer%2Bmit%2Bmikrofon&qid=1624500497&sprefix=bluetooth%2Bkopfh%C3%B6rer%2Bmit%2Bmi%2Caps%2C167&sr=8-5&th=1

I checked the code but haven't found any trace of JS and no position:fixed on the outer div of the image box. Can someone give me an idea what i am supposed to search for to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:sticky;`for the image while the rest are in position relative. For `position:sticky;` be sure to use `top:0px` so it would stick to the topmost part of the screen. If you want to read more about position sticky you go to this [link](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)